# ui-router dynamic controller name

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this state config.

```
          .state(entityId + ".viewOne.estimate", {
        url: "/:stage/:firstTab",
        templateProvider: function ($templateCache, $templateFactory, $stateParams) {

          var templUrl = 'app/modules/' + entityId + '/views/tabs/viewOne/viewOne.' + $stateParams.stage + '.html';

          return $templateCache.get('./' + templUrl) || $templateFactory.fromUrl(templUrl);
        },
        controller: "estimatesCtrl",
        ncyBreadcrumb: { skip: true },
        authenticate: true,
        previousState: entityId,
        showSearchBar: true, // show the search bar in header.subBox.showR.true.html
        resolve: {
          entityModule: function () {
            return {
              value: entityId,
              displayEntity: 'Quote'
            };
          }
        }

      })
```

I also have a parent controller getOneCtrl which loads the record data in the parent state getOneCtrl .state(entityId + ".viewOne

estinatesCtrl is a child controller and its parent is getOneCtrl.

When getOneCtrl loads, there is a field in the data, named 'versionId'

What i am trying to do is, in .state(entityId + ".viewOne.estimate load the controller like this

```
controller: "estinatesCtrl" + versionId
```

Here is the backround story.  As our app expands and new features are introduced inside EstimatesCtrl, the old records in the database might have issues with the the new code.

Going back and "fixing" the old records is not an option.

What we want to achieve is have a field inside every record with a versionId ie: 1.0, 1.2. etc. and also create equivalent versions  of EstimatesCtrl ie, EstimatesCtrl_1_0, EstimatesCtrl_1_1 etc.

When getOneCtrl loads the record details in .state(entityId + ".viewOne., the .state(entityId + ".viewOne.estimate"...  gets the versionId (from getOneCtrl) and loads the equivalent version of "EstimatesCtrl" + versionId.

this way, every record can have its own version of EstimatesCtrl

does that make sense?

Any idea if and how that can be done.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[`controllerProvider`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers) is the best suited option for your case, it will simply look like below.

```
controllerProvider: function($stateParams) {
    var ctrlName = 'estinatesCtrl' + $stateParams.versionId;
    return ctrlName;
}
```

---

Or alternative way could be by using `controller` as function option, that can be supplied in state definition object. For implementing the same, you have to use `$controller` API that provides an option to create a controller in dynamic fashion(generally used in unit test cases to create contrller instance manually).

```
controller: ['$state', '$controller', '$scope', 
    function($state, $controller, $scope) {
       //perhaps you could read versionId from $state/$stateParams as well.
       $controller('estinatesCtrl' + versionId, { $scope: $scope });
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use a dynamic controller name, but you can implement controller functionality dynamically.

In the code below, I define one `dynamicController` which will use the `$injector` to find a builder function by name and use it to build the controller instance.

Notice that each "version" of the controller logic is actually an injectable function registered as a constant.

Also notice that any per-instance injectables such as `$scope` should just be passed through the locals argument.

```
app.controller("dynamicController", function($injector, $scope) {
  var version = 'v1';
  var builder = $injector.get(version + 'ControllerBuilder');
  if (builder) $injector.invoke(builder, this, {$scope:$scope});
});

app.constant("v1ControllerBuilder", function(myService) {
  console.log('Version 1');
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.myService = myService;
  ctrl.myVersion = 1;  
});

app.constant("v2ControllerBuilder", function() {
  console.log('Version 2');
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.myVersion = 2;  
});
```